# How to get unique alias when using more tables in phalcon getSQL() function

Tags: sql, unique, phalcon

I have two tables, and both have 'id' attribute, but return of the getSQL() function looks like this:

```
'SELECT car.id AS id, car.color AS color, car.seat AS seat, 
person.name AS name, person.age AS age... <- I'm missing here the person's 'id'.
```

Is there any option for the getSQL() function, that solves this problem and at each 'id' collision it will get a unique alias name? (e.g. : 'tablename_id')

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the SQL code? In that case I would suggest SELECT car.id as car_id,car.color AS color, car.seat AS seat, 
person.name AS name, person.age AS age, person.id as person_id ..

Comment: I don't want to make the query manually, that's why I use getSQL() function, that doesn't make different alias for same the attributes.


`$query = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($filter->conditions);        
$count = $this->db->fetchAll( "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM(".$query->getSQL()['sql'] . ") AS Filtered", \Phalcon\Db::FETCH_ASSOC, $filter->bind );`

Comment: Are you not using models?